# How to find average mark of an array list that comes from a csv file (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, csv, netbeans-platform

I have a csv file that has a list with student id's, lastname, firstname, marks, phone number, etc. I have organized them into an array list so when you call `stu[100].mark` it will find the mark of the 100th student on the list of the csv file. There are 1000 students. I need to calculate the total overall average mark for all the students (each student only has one mark) I have put it in a loop, but it just prints out their mark. If you need more details, than I apologize.

Here is the code:

public class StudentRecs {

```
public static String user;
public int StuRec;
public static int numstu;
public static double average;
//public static StuRec[] stu;  
static StuRec[] stu = new StuRec[1000];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        stu[i] = new StuRec();
    }
    StuRec stu = new StuRec();
    readFile(user);
    menu();
}
public static String filename;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(filename);

public static Boolean readFile(String filename) throws IOException { //Constructor for filename
    try {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type R To Read a File or Type Default for the default file");
        user = userInput.nextLine();
        if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
            user = userInput.nextLine();
        }
        filename = user;
        if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("default")) {
            filename = "newreg2.csv";
        }


        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            in(input.nextLine());
            numstu++;
        }
        input.close();
        return true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}


public static void in(String reader) {
    String splitter[];
    splitter = reader.split(",");
    stu[numstu] = new StuRec();
    stu[numstu].studentID = splitter[0];
    stu[numstu].lastName = splitter[1];
    stu[numstu].firstName = splitter[2];
    stu[numstu].phoneNumber = splitter[3];
    stu[numstu].courseCode = splitter[4];
    stu[numstu].periodNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitter[5]);  // parseInt turns a string of digits into an integer
    stu[numstu].mark = Integer.parseInt(splitter[6]);
}

public static boolean menu() {
    int total = 0;
    String choice;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("=============================================");
    System.out.println("Type R To Read Another File");
    System.out.println("Type L To Print all File Records");
    System.out.println("Type AA To Print The Average Of All The Marks");
    choice = userInput.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < numstu; i++) {
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
           System.out.println(stu[i].lastName + ", " + stu[i].firstName + ", " + stu[i].studentID + ", " + stu[i].phoneNumber + ", " + stu[i].courseCode + ", " + stu[i].periodNumber + ", " + stu[i].mark);
        }else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R")){

        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("AA")) {
               total = total + stu[i].mark;

        } else {
            System.err.println("Unknown Key Try Again...");

        }

  average = total / 1000;  // compute the average.
     System.out.println(average);    

    } return menu();
```

}
}

Comment: and what is the issue if we may know

Comment: From looking at the code, the error being experienced is probably a StackOverflowError. :)

Comment: Could you post the rest of the class (or at least the relevant parts) - or at least showing where/how the `in` method is called. I believe that is where your problem is best fixed.

Comment: Note that `reader.split` will not work for CSV files, because a value might have a comma in it.  You have to negotiate the commas.  See (http://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/the-only-class-you-need-for-csv-files/)

Comment: A getUserChoice() method would sure make this easier on the eyes.  Also, the missing code makes it difficult to tell for sure but I'd be willing to bet that your usage of `numstu` is going to cause problems.  Also also, your naming sucks, and it does matter.  That last one wasn't mean, it was a prediction of what your teacher will tell you  ;D

Answer (score 2):

Your average routine is computing incorrectly. It's simply taking the n'th mark and adding it to itself, divided by 1000. Since you're using integers, it will just round down, effectively giving you n'th mark + 0 for average on each iteration, leaving you with the last mark on the loop completion.

You need to keep adding to average, and divide by 1000 when you are done to get the value.

```
public static boolean menu() {
    String choice;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("=============================================");
    System.out.println("Type R To Read Another File");
    System.out.println("Type L To Print all File Records");
    System.out.println("Type AA To Print The Average Of All The Marks");
    choice = userInput.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < numstu; i++) {
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
           System.out.println(stu[i].lastName + ", " + stu[i].firstName + ", " + stu[i].studentID + ", " + stu[i].phoneNumber + ", " + stu[i].courseCode + ", " + stu[i].periodNumber + ", " + stu[i].mark);
        }else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R")){

        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("AA")) {
              average += stu[i].mark; // keep adding to average

        } else {
            System.err.println("Unknown Key Try Again...");

        }
    } 
    // divide by zero protection
    if ( numstu > 0 ) {
        average = average/numstu;  // compute the average. Always use the size in terms of a variable whenever possible.
        System.out.println(average); // as noted below, if this is an integer value, < #of students computations will eval to 0.
                                     // might be better to use double
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Oops! No students! :(");
    }
    return menu();
}
```

Note that your menu is a little inefficient, but the problem at hand should be solved.

Comment: Sorry didn't work it printed 0 a thouand times. my apologies i didn't write my question properly there is a list of marks     61,51,81,54,17,51,41,14 etc all the way to 1000. I must add them all together and then divide that total by 1000 to receive grand total average. I appreciate your recommendation on the menu and your help, i was simply not clear.

Comment: Knowing type of `average` is important too. If it happens to be an `int` and is smaller than `1000`, `average / 1000` will evaluate to `0`.

Comment: I've edited the code to take account for that. I also took the print out of the loop, since you don't want 1000 averages. You want one average, computed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the issue with not correctly calculating the sum of the scores, the numerator of the average calculation. I want to focus on the issue of the number of scores, the denominator of the average calculation.

Think real world. As others have mentioned, you cannot depend on the number of students in the file being fixed. File/class size can vary, so you cannot divide by a fixed number.

But neither can you depend on the number of scores being the same as the number of students, so you cannot simply divide by the number of students in that file. A student might not have a mark for a particular assignment (sickness, excused absence, or whatever). A good routine will account for the possibility of blanks (as well as invalid values), and thus I would expect you to need to count the valid, non-blank marks at the same time that you total them so that you can take the appropriate quotient at the end.

Answer (score -1):

This statement is the problem

```
average = stu[i].mark + stu[i].mark / 1000;
```

This does not accumulate a total.  Instead try

```
total = total + stu[i].mark;
```

And then at the end, outside the loop

```
average = total / 1000;
```

Comment: RYAN J SOLVED MY PROBLEM
              THANK YOU EVERYONE WHO HELPED AND GAVE INPUT!

Comment: You should upvote Ryan's solution and accept it then, and consider upvoting AgilePro's answer as well if it was helpful